# request_camera cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I've run into this issue when trying to fire up a camera intent like so:

```
String imagePath;

imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/images/myimage.jpg";
File file = new File( imagePath );
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

The error I'm getting is:
REQUEST_CAMERA cannot be resolved to a variable

Any help is appreciated!

Regards
Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put any integer you want. This is only useful in the onActivityResult.

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick! I'll be able to flag your solution as the answer in a couple of minutes! :)

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
 private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```